# Prolog - Creating predicates

Tags: prolog, predicate

The predicates I'm trying to make in Prolog (through the command line by way of assertions and such) are fairly simple in theory.  The first is one called second(X, List) where it checks to see if X is the second element of the specified list.  The other is called twice([list], X) where putting a list in the left argument prints that list like so:
    [a,b,c]
becomes
    [a,a,b,b,c,c]

Additionally, using that same predicate but with an argument in the right instead of the left should yield some result like this:
    [a,a,b,b]
becomes
    [a,b]

I really don't know how to go about doing either of these.  I get that lists are represented as [head|tail] but I'm still confused.  How can I go about making these predicates?

Comment: Start by reading a tutorial or borrow a Prolog textbook from your nearest library. Then, try something out and if this doesn't work, show what you've got and explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for both: "Tail" is a list, so you can break up a list into `[Head | [Second|Tail] ]`.

You can write the predicate `second(X, List)` in one line using this fact.

Hint for `twice(List, X)` predicate: Use recursion!

- Base case: What should "List" be when "X" is a one-element list?
- Recursive case: Break up List into Head, Second and Tail1. Break up X
  into its Head and Tail2. What needs to be the relationship between
  these values? Make sure twice is called recursively in this.

To see the relationships, notice that `twice([a,a,b,b], [a,b])` should evaluate to true.

In this case, 
`List = [a,a,b,b]`, so `Head = a`, `Second = a` and `Tail1 = [b, b]`.

Also, `X = [a,b]` so `Head = a`, `Tail2 = [b]`. 
So all we need to check is that the two heads and second are all equal, and that `twice(Tail1, Tail2)` is true.

Comment: Why not simply use `[Head, Second|Tail]` instead of `[Head | [Second|Tail] ]`?

Comment: Actually I managed to get it to work.  I did something like second(X, [H,X|T]) and it worked.  For twice, the result was something like twice([A|B], [A,A|C]) :- twice(B,C), but in either case, I got all of them to work.